# How can I receive dhcp6-change action by NetworkManager dispatcher

Tags: network-manager

I add a shell in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/networkmanagerdispatcher.sh

## cat networkmanagerdispatcher.sh

#!/bin/sh

echo "iface=$1 action=$2" >> /data/dispatcher.log
exit 0

then I modify nmcli;
/usr/bin/nmcli connection modify port1 ipv4.method auto
/usr/bin/nmcli connection modify port1 ipv6.method auto
/usr/bin/nmcli device reapply port1

I can only receive dhcp4-change action; no dhcp6-change;

## cat /data/dispatcher.log

iface=port1 action=dhcp4-change

get the ipv6 add and dns from dhcpv6 server.  but no dhcp6-change notify.
:# nmcli con show port1 |grep IP6
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         1510::424d:cb01:2b5c:7e6f/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fe80::416d:63ce:8439:4d53/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2001:4860:4860::8888

nmcli version

## nmcli -v

nmcli tool, version 1.36.2

Answer (score 0):

must use:

```
nmcli connection modify port1 ipv6.method dhcp
```

ipv6.method need to choose dhcp, not auto.